# Reverse for is not a valid view function or pattern name. so acontece em produção

Tags: python-3.x, deploy, django-2.0

Não trabalho a muito tempo com Django porem venho ate aqui me virando + agora cai neste problema ue não estou conseguindo resolver, por isso peço ajuda de quem poder.

Tenho minha aplicação funcionando em desenvolvimento perfeito, porem quando faço o deploy para produção apresenta a seguinte msg:

"Reverse for 'geracontratocompravenda' not found. 'geracontratocompravenda' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

O fato e que em desenvolvimento estou usando python 3.5 com django 2.0.1
no servidor de produção esta com python 3.6 com django 2.0.8.

Tenho desconfiança que possa ser problema de versão pois em desenvolvimento funciona.

Desde a agradeço,

João Neto

**urls.py**

```
url(r'geracontratocompravenda/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
    views.GeraContratoCompraVenda.as_view(),name='geracontratocompravenda'),
```

**views.py**

class GeraContratoCompraVenda(CustomView):

```
permission_codename = 'change_pedidovenda'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    venda_id = kwargs.get('pk', None)
    instance = PedidoVenda.objects.get(id=venda_id)
    instance.status = '2'
    instance.save()
    return redirect(reverse_lazy('vendas:editarpedidovendaview', kwargs={'pk': instance.id}))
```

**No meu html**

href="{% url 'vendas:geracontratocompravenda' object.id %}"

**Traceback**

Environment:

Django Version: 2.0.8
Python Version: 3.6.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'stock.apps.base',
 'stock.apps.login',
 'stock.apps.cadastro',
 'stock.apps.vendas',
 'stock.apps.compras',
 'stock.apps.fiscal',
 'stock.apps.financeiro',
 'stock.apps.estoque']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'stock.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware']

Template error:
In template /home/handson/apps_wsgi/fortcar/templates/base/base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'geracontratocompravenda' not found. 'geracontratocompravenda' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   1 : 
   2 : 
   3 : 
   4 : 
   5 :     {% load staticfiles %}
   6 :     
   7 :     
   8 :     
   9 : 
   10 :

Traceback:

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  447.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "/home/handson/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  634.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /vendas/pedidovenda/editar/2/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'geracontratocompravenda' not found. 'geracontratocompravenda' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Já há alguns anos que não faz nenhum sentido usar versões diferentes do Python e das biblitecs para desenvolveimento e produção - procure a documentação sobre `virtualenv` que permite um ambiente isolado de Python co mas bibliotecas na versão que você escolher, e `pyenv` que permite escolher a versão desejada do Python, independente do sistema operacional.

Comment: Tudo bem foi feito isso com as mesmas versões mesmo assim não esta funcionando alguma outra dica?